Select average difference between timestamps by hour or by day
I have a table (in Microsoft SQL Server 2019) called Orders that is tracking times like this:



ID
EnteredOn
DeliveredTime




111495
2024-04-22 10:35:27.733
2024-04-22 11:29:07.947


111496
2024-04-22 10:42:10.977
2024-04-22 11:26:05.217


111917
2024-04-23 06:57:00.037
2024-04-23 07:42:08.973


111918
2024-04-23 06:57:29.150
2024-04-23 07:39:19.670


112503
2024-04-24 09:06:21.827
2024-04-24 10:01:41.620


112504
2024-04-24 09:07:14.270
2024-04-24 10:17:15.283



My end goal is to return a rolling average, either by hour or by day, depending on the overall time range specified (to save on processing time). As an 'intermediate step' to get where I want, I use DateDiff and Average of DateDiff to calculate the delivery time (in minutes) for each entry along with a simple rolling average, like so:
SELECT
    [EnteredOn] [t_stamp],
    DATEDIFF(minute,EnteredOn,DeliveredTime) [Delivery Time (Minutes)],
    AVG(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,EnteredOn,DeliveredTime)) OVER (ORDER BY EnteredOn) [Average]
FROM Orders

These results look like this:



t _stamp
Delivery Time (Minutes)
Average




2024-04-22 10:35:27.733
54
54


2024-04-22 10:42:10.977
44
49


2024-04-23 06:57:00.037
45
47


2024-04-23 06:57:29.150
42
46


2024-04-24 09:06:21.827
55
48


2024-04-24 09:07:14.270
70
51



When pulling data for the last month (for example), there are an immense amount of records, slowing things down on the end application. I'm looking for a way to avoid pulling each individual record, my main idea being a grouped average so to speak. Ideally, my end result would instead look something like this:



t _stamp
Average by hour




2024-04-22 10:00:00.000
49


2024-04-23 06:00:00.000
44


2024-04-24 09:00:00.000
63



And I'm hoping the end query will be easy enough to switch between grouping/averaging by hour vs. by day -- simply by changing 1 or 2 parameters. I would handle this at the end application. Any ideas? I think I will need to select from a sub-table rather than the core Orders table, but not sure how ...

Do you have an index on EnteredOn that includes DeliveredTime? if not ,come back when you add it if problem still persist. As for your question, you could pregroup the values by doing SUM(DeliveryTime - EnteredOne) and COUNT() and then do the SUM(Delivery) / COUNT() OVER (ORDER BY whatever)

I added an index using the below command and the query at the end application is noticeably faster now. I will still play around with your pregroup idea to improve things even more. Thanks again.
create index deliverytime_index
on Orders(workcell,deliveredtime) where delivered = 1

SQL Server Code:
with T as (
  SELECT *,
    CAST(enteredon AS DATE) [t_stamp],
    DATEDIFF(minute, enteredon, deliveredtime) [Delivery Time (Minutes)]
  FROM Orders
)
select distinct t_stamp,
  round(avg(cast([Delivery Time (Minutes)] as real)/60.0) * 60.0, 2) [Average by hour]
  from T
  group by t_stamp;

Sample Output: db<>fiddle


@Bushmatic please colsed the ticket if issue is resolved
